# How do I manipulate the default import path of a Python Project?

Tags: python, setuptools

This is a little complex, I'll try to simplify as much as possible.

I want to create .pyi files for Brython, in a separate, installable, package.

Consider that I have a main project with a Brython file, `myfile.py`

The file should start with an import exactly like this -- exactly.

```
from browser import document
```

In my installable project, I have a structure such as this;

```
../brython-signatures/src/
└── brython
    ├── browser
    │   ├── document.pyi
    │   └── __init__.py
    └── __init__.py
```

I install this second tool (during testing) with the following;

```
pip install -e ~/Projects/brython-signatures
```

This forces me to use the following import statement;

```
from brython.browser import document
```

For reasons beyond the scope of this question, I do not want to change the structure (e.g. make 'browser' the root package).

**Question** Is there a clever way to make my main application think it should import `browser` instead of `brython.browser`.

I tried adding package-dir entry to the installable project.

```
[package-dir]
browser="src/brython/browser"
```

Comment: Add `~/Projects/brython-signatures/brython` to `sys.path`?

Comment: `sys.path.insert(0,os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))` --> I think that is right, it is kindof a hack though  You would be better off restructuring your project IMO

Comment: Can you paste the line of your `setup.cfg` file where you used `package_dir` ?

Comment: @blhsing, Thanks for the response. However, this is a code-complete problem, not an import one. The reason for the installable project is to provide signature definitions (.pyi) where they do not currently exist. Essentially, I want to add signature stubs to Brython - where they do not currently exist.

Comment: Thanks, @Alexander, for the response -- please see my response to blhsing. With respect to restructure, the "browser" object is one of the various domains used by Brython that I need to allow import of. Even if I moved it up a level to fix the inport, as soon as I needed another domain (package), I'd face the same issue.